# How to hide filesystems from the launcher in unity

Tags: unity, launcher, chromebook

Sorry if this is a silly question - I'm not really experienced in Ubuntu.

I have recently enabled my Chromebook to dual-boot with Ubuntu using crouton. In the launcher, I can see some applications, but also 3 file systems. I think that they're partitions of the solid state storage on my laptop - they won't open and it gives me an error, which is fine because I don't need to use them from Ubuntu, but is there an easy way to hide them from view? I don't want to unmount them in case it mucks things up.

Thanks,
Archie

Answer (score 3):

Open up disk utility by pressing pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> and type in

```
gnome-disks
```

Click on the gear icon then click on Edit Mount Options.

[image]

Set Automatic Mount Options to Off by clicking it.
untick "Show in user interface" just like in the screen shot. then click OK.

[image]
after this step you will need to remount the drive if the drive is not mounted. then you don't need to do any thing.

and now it should be gone from the user interface.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Does Disks make changes to `/etc/fstab` or do you know what config files it edits?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes disks makes changes to '/etc/fstab' file

Comment: Interesting, was just wondering if Unity's launcher only listens to /etc/fstab, or if it had other config files somewhere else too